# How to use Perl's XML::XPath with non-English element names?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, utf-8

How can I work with [XML::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) when some elements' names are not in English?

I use Strawberry Perl.

I get `employees.xml` and `train_xml.pl` from web, they work good.

But when When I add some Chinese characters, I get the following error:

> `Wide character in die at D:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/XPath/Parser.pm line 189.`
>
> ```
> Query:
> /employees/employee[@age="30"]/工作...
> ..............................^^^
> Invalid query somewhere around here (I think)
> ```

How can I solve this?

`employees.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<employees>
    <employee age="30">
        <name>linux</name>
    <country>US</country>
    <工作>教师</工作>
    </employee>
    <employee age="10">
    <name>mac</name>
    <country>US</country>
    </employee>
    <employee age="20">
    <name>windows</name>
    <country>US</country>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

`train_xml.pl`:

```
use Encode;
use XML::XPath->new;
use utf8;
my $xp=XML::XPath->new(filename=>"employees.xml");
print $xp->findvalue('/employees/employee[@age="10"]/name'),"\n";
my $path1 = '/employees/employee[@age="30"]/工作';
print $xp->findvalue($path1),"\n";
```

Comment: Does it get the right result for the first query? It looks like it's just having issues parsing the second query rather than any problems with your XML

Comment: Yes,the first query from web is right.  the second query that I added isn't right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( );

{
   my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
   my $doc = $parser->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   say $doc->findvalue('/employees/employee[@age="10"]/name');
   say $doc->findvalue('/employees/employee[@age="30"]/工作');
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a a.xml
mac
教师
```

---

If you want to keep using the (buggy, slower, and far-less-widely used) [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::XPath), you can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use feature qw( say );

use XML::XPath qw( );

{ # Monkeypatch XML::XPath.
   package XML::XPath::Parser;

   # Colon removed from these definitions.
   my $NameStartCharClassBody = "a-zA-Z_\\xC0-\\xD6\\xD8-\\xF6\\xF8-\\x{2FF}\\x{370}-\\x{37D}\\x{37F}-\\x{1FFF}\\x{200C}-\\x{200D}\\x{2070}-\\x{218F}\\x{2C00}-\\x{2FEF}\\x{3001}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFFD}\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}";
   my $NameCharClassBody = "${NameStartCharClassBody}\\-.0-9\\xB7\\x{300}-\\x{36F}\\x{203F}-\\x{2040}";
   my $Name = "(?:[$NameStartCharClassBody][$NameCharClassBody]*)";

   $NCName = $Name;
   $QName = "$NCName(?::$NCName)?";
   $NCWild = "${NCName}:\\*";
}

{
   my $doc = XML::XPath->new(filename => $ARGV[0]);
   say $doc->findvalue('/employees/employee[@age="10"]/name');
   say $doc->findvalue('/employees/employee[@age="30"]/工作');
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a a.xml
mac
教师
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your two answers are instructive to me.

Comment: Got lucky with ::Parser storing the patterns in global variables!

Answer (score 3):

You should, always, *without exception* post the actual code you run, not gibberish like:

```
use XML::XPath->new;
```

Now, as for this issue, I am fairly certain this is caused by [this line in `XML/XPath/Parser.pm`](https://github.com/manwar/XML-XPath/blob/d39003bd2306d0c4296ae5dacb5816ea3d0fe610/lib/XML/XPath/Parser.pm#L45):

> ```
> $NCName = '([A-Za-z_][\w\\.\\-]*)';
> ```

which, for reasons with which I am not familiar, requires that the first character of an element be restricted to the set of English letters and `_`. Here is a simple test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*DATA );

my $good_path = '/employees/employee[@age="30"]/yağcı';
my $bad_path = '/employees/employee[@age="30"]/şımarık';

say $xp->findvalue($good_path);

say $xp->findvalue($bad_path);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<employees>
    <employee age="30">
        <şımarık>değil</şımarık>
        <yağcı>değil</yağcı>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Output:

```
C:\...\> perl x.pl
değil
Query:
/employees/employee[@age="30"]/şımarık...
..............................^^^
Invalid query somewhere around here (I think)
```

If I change that pattern to:

> ```
> $NCName = '(\w[\w\\.\\-]*)';
> ```

I get the output:

```
C:\...\> perl x.pl
değil
değil
```

and, using your original data, I get:

```
değil
教师
```

after making the appropriate changes.

That is not the correct pattern to use, but I did this to make sure that my hunch as to the cause was correct by making the smallest change possible. The correct specification is [in the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name):

```
Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*

NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] |
                  [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] |
                  [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] |
                  [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] |
                  [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 |
                  [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

[Issue opened](https://github.com/manwar/XML-XPath/issues/4).

The [module has been patched](https://github.com/manwar/XML-XPath/commit/b9fe95de56c85c8a858492325d7e1834d9882655). You can download [version 1.41](https://metacpan.org/release/MANWAR/XML-XPath-1.41) or later test.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.